# MATLAB Histogram Problems

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, histogram

I need to calculate the probability density of the function 1/2-x where x is a randomly generated number between 0 and 1.

My code looks like this:

```
n=10^6;
b=10^2;

x=(1./(2-(rand(1,n))));

a=histfit(x,b,'kernel'); % Requires Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox
xlim([0.5 1.0])
```

And I get a decent graph that looks like this:

[image]

As it may be apparent, there are a couple of problems with this:

1. MATLAB draws a fit that differs from my histogram, because it counts in the empty space outside the `[0.5 1]` range of the function as well. This results in a distorted fit towards the edges. (The reason you don't see said empty space is because I entered an xlim there)
2. I don't know how I could divide every value in the Y-axis by 10^6, which would give me my probability density.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: but the `kernel` method does a 100 windowed average of your data, this is why it is designed for continuous data...I do not think you can avoid this behavior unless you extend your data and discard the first and last bins of your histogram...

Comment: That's what I thought, how do I extend the data though? I don't *have* to use kernel so if there's a better option I'd like to know. Others give curves that aren't fit at all.

Answer (score 3):

To solve both of your problems, I suggest using `hist` (Note if you have a version above 2010b, you should use `histogram` instead) instead of `histfit` to first get the values of your histogram and then doing a regression and plotting them:

```
n=10^6;
b=10^2;
x=(1./(2-(rand(1,n))));

[counts,centers]=hist(x,b);
density = counts./trapz(centers, counts);
%// Thanks to @Arpi for this correction 
polyFitting = polyfit(centers,density,3)
polyPlot = polyval(polyFitting,centers)
figure
bar(centers,density)
hold on
plot(centers,polyPlot,'r','LineWidth',3)
```

You can also up the resolution by adjusting b, which is set to 100 currently. Also try different regressions to see which one you prefer.

[image: result looks like]

Comment: The correct density would be `counts/trapz(centers, counts)`. I would be cautious with using a polynomial to represent a cdf function, some theoretical justifications always should be preferred.

Comment: True, as for using a polynomial to represent this cdf function, I used this for simplicity, I guess the OP could use any type of fitting that s/he prefers.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Better result can be obtained by using `ksdensity` and specifying the support of the distribution.

**2.** By using `hist` you have access to the counts and centers, thus the normalization to get density is straightforward.

Code to demonstrate the suggestions:

```
rng(125)
n=10^6;
b=10^2;

x=(1./(2-(rand(1,n))));

subplot(1,2,1)
a = histfit(x,b,'kernel');
title('Original')
xlim([0.5 1.0])

[f,c] = hist(x,b);
% normalization to get density
f = f/trapz(c,f);

% kernel density
pts = linspace(0.5, 1, 100);
[fk,xk] = ksdensity(x, pts, 'Support', [0.5, 1]);

subplot(1,2,2)
bar(c,f)
hold on
plot(xk,fk, 'red', 'LineWidth', 2)
title('Improved')
xlim([0.5 1.0])
```

Comparing the results:
[image]

**EDIT:** If you do not like the endings:

```
pts = linspace(0.5, 1, 500);
[fk,xk] = ksdensity(x, pts, 'Support', [0.5, 1]);
bar(c,f)
hold on
plot(xk(2:end-1),fk(2:end-1), 'red', 'LineWidth', 2)
title('Improved_2')
xlim([0.5 1.0])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I get the same problem when I enlarge the graph. It's definitely improved however.

Comment: I wouldn't call it the same problem since the improved kernel density function has support of [0.5, 1.0] compared with the original solution that extends over that. If you do not like the sharply dropping endings you can simple leave out the first and last elements of `fk` and `xk`. The support ends can be reached by extrapolation. The accuracy can be improved by more points `pts`.